# How to make multiple action in HTML form

Tags: html, forms, action

Say I want to make double action in HTML form.

1. The first action would be to examle1.php
2. And the second action would be to example2.php

I have code like this

```
<form name="input" action="" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So, how to insert the 2 actions above to the `action=""`?
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You may want to consider using some clever JavaScript. With jQuery you can easily send data using AJAX in conjunction with (or slightly before) the HTML-defined action is carried out.

Comment: Deal with this server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**. You can have only one declared `action` attribute for the `<form>`

You can however, try:

- Doing an AJAX POST for your *first action* and submitting the actual form on its success handler
- Writing the server side script for your *first action* such that it redirects to your *second action* after it done.

Comment: Thank you techfoobar for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

In a form you can give only one action="action.php". But tell us why you want to have two actions ?

Comment: Oke now I know :). Actually, I want to add additional operation in the Magento form action. But I don't know where to add it. I hope you understand what I mean...